# MarkMail preview

Tags: marklogic

Can anyone share what software MarkLogic uses to generate preview images for the attachments in their [Markmail](http://markmail.org/) software for attachments? It seems to be doing a good job with office documents as well. I tried OpenOffice to convert to PDF and then generate images for each page in PDF, but the conversion did not do a good job, especially with images embedded in the documents.

I am trying to create a CPF task which converts documents (all types or most used types) to images of individual pages (if present). Office documents especially Excel and PPT are proving to be hassle. I also want to keep the extracted text from the documents have page nos.. and other stuff like title, header, footer etc.. so when doing snippets, I can use these tags to highlight (in-fact want to do how markmail does :)).

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What we do on MarkMail.org is use an external "headless" OpenOffice.org process to "print" each Office file format to PDF.  Then we use [PDF2Image](https://www.pdftron.com/pdf2image/) to generate the images and thumbnails from each page.  If you're having trouble with this step it could be that you're using ImageMagick, which we found wasn't as robust as PDF2Image.

We use MarkLogic's internal `xdmp:pdf-convert` to capture the text on every page of the PDF.  We embed the extracted text into the email message document to make it searchable, along with the URIs to the various binaries.

We use a Java loader to drive the process (and a fairly complex Java class to drive OpenOffice.org).  We noticed OpenOffice.org sometimes gets itself stuck, so we also have an external monitoring process that kicks OOo when that happens.  Loading the OpenOffice.org mailing lists was a particular challenge because the list is full of people writing in saying, "Hey the attached file causes OpenOffice.org big problems".  Yep.

We didn't use CPF.  All emails get loaded via the same Java pipeline so no need.

Something interesting we learned: Right now the Java loader "pushes" the file to OpenOffice.org for conversion.  A better approach would've been to load the mail first, then let a client process poll for new mails with Office files needing processing.  The pull model would've made it less important that OpenOffice.org be up and available all the time.  It also would've made it easier to rerun past processing after improving the pipeline, like after an OpenOffice.org upgrade.

All in all, we're pretty happy with the system.  Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info.. I use the same mechanism for converting to pdf, but I noticed it is not behaving properly when it comes to PPT and Excel.. It looses formatting and also sometimes places text in wrong place.. Did you encounter the same ?

xdmp:pdf-covert , will keep the page nos. etc.. when text is extracted ?

Comment: You're saying OpenOffice.org isn't doing the right thing? We've had good success, but perhaps your trouble is with pptx and xlsx files which we never tried because that was added in OOo 3.x after we went live. If you think you need the Java file to drive the process, message me on twitter at my same handle as here. The pdf-convert can keep the page numbers, yes. If you have trouble and need sample code, message me.